For real numbers, $c_1,\ldots,c_n$, define a matrix $A=(a_{i,j})$ s.t. $a_{i,i+1}=c_i$, $a_{n,1}=c_n$ and all other entries are zero.
This question was asked in the TIFR 2025 GS1 test (question number 16 in the MCQ section). I'm modifying the question a little bit to avoid the trouble of typing out the choices...

Let $n>1$ be a positive integer. Let $A=(a_{i,j})$ be an $n\times n$ matrix such that $a_{i,i+1}=c_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$, and $a_{n,1}=c_n$, where $c_1$, $\ldots$, $c_n$ are real numbers and all other entries are zero. Show that $\det(I-A^n)=0$ if $\prod_{i=1}^n c_i=1$.

When I was taking the test, I couldn't do it. I managed to do it later ; I'm asking this question to share my solution. I would want to see alternative solutions as well!

I actually had a similar question on an exam I had to do for Linear Algebra so I'm rehashing some ideas from there.
Approach 1 (Slightly Less Elegant Approach)
Note that this is by no means a formal proof but just intuition behind a proof. We first claim that $A^n=I_n$. The general idea is to use the fact that $A$ is very similar to a permutation matrix (a matrix with each row and column only containing one entry with $1$ and all others $0$ in which it can be shown that for a $n \times n$ permutation matrix $P$, $P^n=1$). Consider the basis $C_n=\{c'_1,c'_2,\dots,c'_n\}$ where $c'_1=(c_1,0,0,\dots,0)$, $c'_2=(0,c_2,0,\dots,0)$, etc. For a concrete example, we consider the $n=4$ case, but this applies in general. Then we have
\begin{align}
Ac'_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & c_4c_1 \end{pmatrix} \\
Ac'_2=\begin{pmatrix} c_1c_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
Ac'_3=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & c_2c_3 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
Ac'_4=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & c_3c_4 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
\end{align} which formally should be written as column matrices. Then let's just consider $A^2$, this gives
$$A^2=A\times \begin{pmatrix}| & | & | & | \\ c'_4 & c'_1 & c'_2 & c'_3 \\ | & | & | & | \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & c_1c_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & c_2c_3 \\ c_3c_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & c_4c_1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
From which can see that  that transforming $A$ with $A$ actually shifts all the elements in each row to the right and multiplies it by the 'next' $c_i$ so to speak. In general, for the $n$th case, that means that $A^n$ shifts each element of $A$ to the right $n-1$ times, which results in a diagonal matrix, and each $c_i$ is multiplied by the remaining $c_1,\dots,c_{i-1},c_{i+1},\dots, c_n$. In other words $$A^n=\begin{pmatrix}c_1\cdots c_n & 0 & \cdots &0 & 0 \\ 0 & c_1\cdots c_n & \cdots &0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & c_1\cdots c_n & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & c_1\cdots c_n \end{pmatrix}=\prod^n_{i=1}c_i \cdot I_n =I_n$$ where the last equality follows from the fact that $\prod^n_{i=1}c_i=1$. Then since $A^n=I_n$,  $\det(A^n-I_n)=\det(0)=0$ as desired.
Approach 2 (Better Approach)
I think this is a more elegant solution. We begin by showing that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, in other words, we need a vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax=1\cdot x$. This is bit random but this holds for the vector $$x=(1,\tfrac{1}{c_1},\tfrac{1}{c_1 c_2},\cdots,\tfrac{1}{c_1 c_2\cdots c_{n-1}}).$$ This works because by explicit calculation $$Ax=(1,\tfrac{1}{c_1},\tfrac{1}{c_1 c_2},\cdots, \tfrac{1}{c_1 \cdots c_{n-2}} ,c_n)$$
and from the condition given $c_1\cdots c_n=1$, so $c_n=\frac{1}{c_1 \cdots c_{n-1}}$ which gives $$Ax=(1,\tfrac{1}{c_1},\tfrac{1}{c_1 c_2},\cdots, \tfrac{1}{c_1 \cdots c_{n-2}} ,c_n)= (1,\tfrac{1}{c_1},\tfrac{1}{c_1 c_2},\cdots, \tfrac{1}{c_1 \cdots c_{n-2}}, \tfrac{1}{c_1 \cdots c_{n-1}})=x.$$
So $1$ is indeed an eigenvalue of $A$. This also by definition means that $\det(A-I_n)=0$ or  $\det(I_n-A)=0$. From here we can take 2 sub-approaches.
Sub-Approach 1
For $\det(I_n-A^n)$ we have $$\det(I_n-A^n)=\det\big((I_n-A_n)(I_n+A_n+\cdots+A_n^{n-1})\big)=\det(I_n-A_n)\det(I_n+\cdots+A_n^{n-1})=0$$ as desired.
Sub-Approach 2
We claim that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$. By definition, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then there exists an $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$. Now consider $A^nx$ for the same $x$. Then $$A^nx=A^{n-1}(Ax)=A^{n-1}\lambda x=\lambda A^{n-2}(Ax)=\lambda^2A^{n-2}x=\cdots=\lambda^nx$$ so by definition $\lambda^n$ is indeed an eigenvalue of $A^n$. Then because $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, $1^n=1$ is an eigenavalue of $A^n$ which means $\det(A^n-1\cdot I_n)=0$ from which it follows that $$\det(A^n-1\cdot I_n)=(-1)^n\det(I_n-A^n)=0$$ as desired.

Here's a way to find the eigenvector $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^t$ without guessing. We need $DPx=x$ i.e., $Px=D^{-1}x$ i.e., $$(x_2,\ldots,x_n,x_1)^t=\big(\frac{x_1}{c_1},\ldots,\frac{x_{n-1}}{c_{n-1}}, \frac{x_n}{c_n}\big)^t$$ We see that $x_2=\frac{x_1}{c_1}$, $\ldots$, $x_n=\frac{x_{n-1}}{c_{n-1}}$, $x_1=\frac{x_n}{c_n}$. Letting $x_1=1$ gives $x_2=\frac{1}{c_1}$, $x_3=\frac{1}{c_1c_2}$, $\ldots$, $x_n=\frac{1}{c_1c_2\ldots c_{n-1}}$. This is perhaps less "random"? You only have to guess that $1$ is an eigenvalue which is fair enough since the question requires you to prove that $\det(I-A^n)=0$.

Yeah you're right!

For the sake of simplicity, I would first do it for $n=3$.
We observe that $A=\pmatrix{0&c_1&0\\0&0&c_2\\c_3&0&0}=\underbrace{\pmatrix{c_1\\&c_2\\&&c_3}}_{=\,D}\underbrace{\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0}}_{\,=P}.\tag*{}$
This observation alone pushed me to the solution! Let $\sigma=(123)\in S_3$.
Let $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ be the standard ordered basis of $\mathbb R^{3\times 1}$. 
$P=\pmatrix{e_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}\mid e_{\sigma^{-1}(2)}\mid e_{\sigma^{-1}(3)}}$ is basically the matrix of the permutation $\sigma^{-1}$.
Now,
$A = DP$
$A^2=DPDP=D(PDP^{-1})P^2$
$A^3=D(PDP^{-1})P^2DP=D(PDP^{-1})(P^2DP^{-2})P^3$
Since $P^3=I$, $D=\text{diag}(c_1,c_2,c_3)$, $PDP^{-1}=\text{diag}(c_{\sigma(1)},c_{\sigma(2)}, c_{\sigma(3)})$, $P^2DP^{-2}=\text{diag}(c_{\sigma^2(1)},c_{\sigma^2(2)}, c_{\sigma^2(3)})$, $A^3$ simplifies to $c_1c_2c_3 I$.
Note: In general, let $X=(x_{ij})$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. If $P_\pi=(e_{\pi(1)}\mid\ldots\mid e_{\pi(n)})$ is the matrix of a permutation $\pi\in S_n$ then the $(i,j)$-entry of $P_\pi^{-1}XP_{\pi}$ is $x_{\pi(i)\,\pi(j)}$.

For general case, we begin with $\sigma=(12\ldots n)\in S_n$.
Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be the standard ordered basis of $\mathbb R^{n\times 1}$. 
$P=\pmatrix{e_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}\mid \ldots\mid e_{\sigma^{-1}(n)}}$ is the matrix of the permutation $\sigma^{-1}$.
For $k=0,\ldots,n-1$, let $D_k=\text{diag}(c_{\sigma^k(1)},\ldots,c_{\sigma^k(n)})$.
We have:
$A=D_0P$
$A^2=D_0(PD_0P^{-1})P^2$
$\vdots$
$A^n=(\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(P^kD_0P^{-k}))P^n$
Now using $P^n=I$ and $P^kD_0P^{-k}=D_k$, we get $$A^n= D_0D_1\ldots D_{n-1}=c_1c_2\ldots c_n I.$$
The statement to prove follows directly. $\blacksquare$

Alternative approach inspired by  d0uble_a_b4ttery's answer:
The original question requires us to show that $\det(I-A^{n})=0$ which is equivalent to $``$$1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^n$.$"$
We claim that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ i.e., $\exists$ a non-zero vector $x\in\mathbb R^{n\times 1}$ s.t. $Ax=x$. It would follow that $A^nx=x$ and hence, $1$ would also be an eigenvalue of $A^n$ thereby completing the proof.
To prove that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, we explicitly find an eigenvector $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^t$.
We need $DPx=x$ i.e., $Px=D^{-1}x$ i.e., $$(x_2,\ldots,x_n,x_1)^t=\bigg(\frac{x_1}{c_1},\ldots,\frac{x_{n-1}}{c_{n-1}}, \frac{x_n}{c_n}\bigg)^t$$
This leads to a system of $n$ equations. $x$ exists iff this system is consistent.
We get these equations: $x_2=\frac{x_1}{c_1}$, $\ldots$, $x_n=\frac{x_{n-1}}{c_{n-1}}$, $x_1=\frac{x_n}{c_n}$. Letting $x_1=1$, the first $n-1$ equations give: $x_2=\frac{1}{c_1}$, $x_3=\frac{1}{c_1c_2}$, $\ldots$, $x_n=\frac{1}{c_1c_2\cdots c_{n-1}}$. The last equation gives $x_n=c_n$ which is in agreement with $x_n=\frac{1}{c_1c_2\ldots c_{n-1}}$ since $\prod c_i=1$.
Thus, $x=\left(1,\frac{1}{c_1},\frac{1}{c_1c_2},\ldots,\frac{1}{c_1c_2\cdots c_{n-1}}\right)^t$ is an eigenvector of $A$ w.r.t. $1$. $\blacksquare$

This is another approach that I thought of... This is perhaps the simplest one! The idea is to write everything in standard ordered basis of $M_n(\mathbb R)$.
Let $E_{ij}$ denote the matrix all whose entries are $0$ except the $(i,j)$-entry which is $1$.
We write $$A=\sum_{i}\sum_j a_{ij}E_{ij}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}c_iE_{i,i+1} + c_nE_{n,1}.$$
Now, we'll do an indexing game... Let $\sigma = (12\ldots n)\in S_n$ then we can write:
$$A=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_iE_{i,\sigma(i)}.$$
To find $A^2$, we'll use the fact $E_{ij}E_{rs}=E_{is}$ if $j=r$; otherwise $E_{ij}E_{rs}=\mathbf 0$ if $j\neq r$.
$$A^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n c_ic_jE_{i,\sigma(i)}E_{j,\sigma(j)}$$
Now, the only term that would survive in the inner sum is $j=\sigma(i)$ so, we have:
$$A^2=\sum_{i=1}^n c_ic_{\sigma(i)}E_{i,\sigma(i)}E_{\sigma(i),\sigma^2(i)}$$
which simplifies to:
$$A^2=\sum_{i=1}^n c_ic_{\sigma(i)}E_{i,\sigma^2(i)}.$$
Ready for what's next?
$$A^3=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i\,c_{\sigma(i)}\,c_{\sigma^2(i)}\,E_{i,\sigma^3(i)}$$
By induction, we can show that:
$$A^k=\sum_{i=1}^k c_i\,c_{\sigma(i)}\,\ldots\,c_{\sigma^{k-1}(i)}\,E_{i,\sigma^k(i)}.$$
$\sigma^n=\text{id}$ and for each index $i$, the coefficient $c_i\,c_{\sigma(i)}\,\ldots\,c_{\sigma^{n-1}(i)}$ is just a rearrangement of the product $c_1c_2\ldots c_n$ so, we have:
$$ A^n =c_1c_2\ldots c_n\sum_{i=1}^n E_{i,i}=c_1c_2\ldots c_n I.$$
The statement follows directly. $\blacksquare$
